# What happens to existing messages in SQS when I add HTTP SNS subscription?

Tags: amazon-sns

I have an existing SQS with X number of messages. I add new SNS HTTP subscription for it. Will my HTTP service receive all of the existing messages from the queue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No only the new messages get sent.

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to push existing messages to the SNS HTTP subscription without creating custom code?

Comment: @Alex S, no, you will have to receive those messages.